# How to get rid of the gray tile fade-out effect in Leaflet maps?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I was working on a geospatial data solutions which requires monitoring project locations on a daily basis. I want to make this experience pleasant for the end users.

1. How do I manage removing the tile fade-out effect post zooming into the map?(Zoom Event)
2. How do I manage removing the tile fade-out effect during the demonstration of fly-over event?(Fly-over event)

I believe the following GIFs give a better idea of the area turning gray and tiles fading out post the zoom and fly-over event.

1. Zoom-out event.
   [image: Tile fade-out post zoom out.]
2. Fly-over event.
3. [image: Tile fade-out during fly-over event.]

Note: I've used no web frameworks and tried using the code from [Leaflet tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/) to see how leaflet apps look and feel in terms of user-experience.

```
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{ 
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);
```

I truly believe the person using my product must have premium level experience, for which I seek the help of mapbox/leaflet developers' expertise in guiding me through this small obstacle. Thank you.

Comment: Leaflet does not fade-out tiles (unless you explicitly load a [plugin](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.GridLayer.FadeOut)). What you're seeing is the default background grey wherever there are no tiles loaded, plus some glitches due to the map container being resized by overuse of web frameworks. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: @IvanSanchez, I've updated the question. Just wanted to ask if this is the default behavior of leaflet apps, then can't it be overridden? I've built similar apps in Mapbox but the zoom-out and flyover transitions look smooth and differ from this.

Comment: You don't want to ask if that's the default, because you say that you've checked the default already. I think you're lacking vocabulary and concepts, so watch https://av.tib.eu/media/20375 and go through https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#tile-load